# If you hang a mass with a rope on a wheel, how do you calculate the resulting moment of inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string, moment-of-inertia

How do you calculate the moment of inertia of the left object with axis of rotation in M. Is it the moment of inertia of the wheel $I$ and the $m *r^2$, where $r$ is the position vector of $m$ w.r.t. to the point centre $M$?

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't add $mr^{2}$. What you need to do is to break down the question into pieces. You solve the equation of motion for your hanging mass, and the equation of motion (angular acceleration) for the cylinder. The tension in the spring appears in both, and there will be a connection between the acceleration of the falling body and the angular acceleration of the cylinder. The object with mass $m$ is not rotating, is falling. Its equation of motion is simply $m\vec{g} -\vec{T}  = m \vec{ a}$. For the cylinder you have $\alpha \frac{MR^{2}}{2}=TR$, where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration, now if you add the connection between $\alpha$ and $a$ you will have three equations with three unknowns: $T$, $a$ and $\alpha$.